# How to override SourceViewerConfiguration in eclipse text editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hover

I am making eclipse plugin text hover that extends from the eclipse text hover.
I am trying to make my own "Design" for the text hover using the method

```
public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator()
```

in my own TextHover class but, the information I give in the function return to default when I focused on my hover.
I read that I need to set the IInformationControlCreator in the SourceViewerConfiguration class using the following function:

```
getInformationControlCreator
```

But, I can't override the SourceViewerConfiguration.

This is my override function:

```
package TextHoverPackage;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextHover;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.ISourceViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration;
public class TextHoverSourceViewerConfig extends SourceViewerConfiguration {
    public ITextHover getTextHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer, String contentType) {
        System.out.println("I am in other place!!!");
        return new JavaTextHover();
    }
}
```

The "I am in other place!!!" message is not printed
I tried to wrote this class in extension point in the plugin.xml page but I get an error that extension point for this class:

```
org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration
```

can't be create.

So I will be happy to know how to override the SourceViewerConfiguration class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the main `SourceViewerConfiguration` for an existing editor.

The only way to set a different `SourceViewerConfiguration` is to create a new editor.

Comment: So how could I change the texthover inforamtion that won't disappear when I focus on the TextHover?